# Recovery disk of Acer Aspire not working, also deleted recovery partition

Tags: windows, data-recovery, acer-aspire

I'm using an Acer Aspire 5742g. It is under warranty, but by mistake I had deleted the recovery partition on the hard disk, which was around about 13-14 GB in size.

I had created recovery discs before, but they are not running now. I think they are corrupted.

How can I restore the OS? Is there are any ways to download those discs?

Comment: If it is under warrenty then you should open a ticket with Acer, who should provide downloads or send you new recovery media.

Comment: I think you can get recovery media when it is out of warranty for a fee?

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question to include the exact problem you are having when trying to run the recovery discs, maybe we can help solve that.

Comment: If installing the same version of Windows the PC came with _(download from Microsoft)_, it will auto-activate Windows  _(Windows Update may need to be run first)_ since OEM keys are saved in the BIOS/UEFI firmware. All the OEM recovery partition contains are a handful of scripts for WinRE that formats `C:` and applies the `.wim`/`.esd`/`.swm` image via `Dism` _(likely `ImageX` when this question was written)_. WIMs/ESDs are the native Windows filesystem images captured via `Dism` [≥8] or `ImageX` [XP ≤ 7], whereas SWM images are split-WIMs split into specific sizes due to size constraints.

Answer (score 0):

If you acquire a copy of whichever retail, as opposed to OEM, Windows version – presumably in this case Windows 7 Home Premium, and probably 64-bit – you can reinstall using that.

Then, install the correct drivers for your model. If you also made the drivers and apps disc, run that; if not download them from the Acer Support site for your model.

Probably most people would think this is advocating piracy, but it is the key that matters, not the media. There is nothing untoward about downloading an unadulterated copy of Windows that requires a key to work properly and using your own key to activate it! If it was the wrong key for the media, it wouldn't be accepted.

The key on the bottom of the laptop will work, though a handy tip is while the original installation is still running, to find the key currently in use (the one Acer use when they install Windows at the factory, and which doesn't need activating [Belarc Advisor](http://www.belarc.com/free_download.html) will do this. If one of the keys – either the factory installation key or the one on the bottom of the laptop – doesn't work, the other one will.

You can find the copy of Windows at torrent sites, the trick being to identify the copy you require at the [MSDN download portal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/subscriptions/downloads/default.aspx#searchTerm=&ProductFamilyId=350&Languages=en&PageSize=10&PageIndex=0&FileId=0), where they give the hashes, then Google the SHA1 hash to find the claimed unaltered torrent and compare it once downloaded.

If it matches, it's just as it came from Microsoft and safe to burn to DVD and install. A freeware called [HashTab](http://implbits.com/HashTab/HashTabWindows.aspx) is an excellent easy-to-use tool for doing the comparison with.

Comment: The key on the original install is a SLP version, and you'd either be able to install without being asked the keys, or not at all. The sticker key is a better bet here.